# Can't add VS command prompt as a tool in VS15 Community

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmd

[image]

**Arguments: /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"**

I want to add visual studio command prompt as a tool. I try with all kind of ways, but still can't able to open vs cmd.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is what cmd shows when i run CMD tool. 
**Framework: .NET Framework 4.6**

Can anyone tell me where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken (I have several Visual Studio versions installed so I'm talking from memory here), Visual Studio 2015 uses `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` as a folder. You are using `12.0` which won't more likely contain a `VsDevCmd.bat` file (not even a `Tools` folder inside `Common7`).

Try changing it to `/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

Answer (score 1):

Check the double quote at the end of your argument. It seems like you didnt put it.

Comment: How do you know? To me, he clearly writes `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` in his question.

Comment: Note this line  " 'C:\Program' is not recognized" it stops at the first white space ! I think there is something missing in the end of the string.